# Cannot Resolve Type Spring Project In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So my spring project on eclipse was working fine, I returned to my project a week ago and for some reason there are squiggly red lines every where, saying cannot resolve type all over the whole project. I have tried everything on the internet and dont know the way forward now.

This is what I see when I run gradle

```
    Working Directory: /Users/deso/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE/dohinventoryfordoh
Gradle user home: /Users/deso/.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.6
Java Home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: build

:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:.
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:.
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
  Required by:
      project :
> Could not find org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:.
  Required by:
      project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild.

Comment: For what's it''s worth, you can try this: Windows–>Preferences–>Java–>Compiler–>Building–>Output folder–>”Rebuild class files modified by others”, and then  click on "Apply and Close".

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have done that but i see nothing, Project-> Clean

Comment: @Hua ```Rebuild class files modified by others``` was already checked